# After upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 unable to install php

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, php

I have done a release upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Removed previously installed PHP. Then I run

`sudo apt install php-cli`

but I encounter the error below:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-cli : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4) but 7.4.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 is to be installed
              Depends: php7.4-json but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.4-opcache but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.4-readline but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so I suspect `7.4.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3` package is still active? I have checked `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and didn't found any source matching that package.

Where else should I look?

**Edit**

`apt policy php7.4-common`

```
php7.4-common:
  Installed: 7.4.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3
  Candidate: 7.4.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3
  Version table:
 *** 7.4.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.4.3-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy php7.4-common`.

Comment: You might have some custom "sources" in your apt configuration? Have a look in the software manager and see if that is the case

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first ? This command will update the package "database" with a list of newest available package versions.

Comment: @pLumo i've updated the question. SorenA Yes I did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You uninstalled `php`, but not it's dependencies, so there are still leftovers from the `ppa` (I guess it was [`ppa:ondrej/php`](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/)).

Try `autoremove`, it may already be enough:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

If not, you can manually uninstall the packages in question:

```
sudo apt remove php7.4-common
```

If that is not enough, it might help adding the `ppa`  again and remove with `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php
```

Comment: it seems ondrej/php was pointing to bionic but it was unchecked (disabled?) when I did the upgrade. From "Software and Updates" I removed it then I updated apt using `sudo apt update`. Then I removed `php7.4-common` as per your instruction. It seems there were some leftover packages as well. Now I was able to reinstall PHP. Thanks a lot!